# Is there a way to maintain frequently updating state efficiently in an immutable structure, or should I be using a partially mutable structure?

Tags: kotlin, state-management, compose-multiplatform

I am trying to replicate a node-based UI in Compose.

I draw the outlines for my nodes using `Card`, and thought I would be clever by minimising the requirements for calling the method, so that the caller only needed to provide the offset, and a method which would be called when the offset is changed. That way, the caller should have the greatest flexibility in how they represent the data.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NodeBodyContainer(
    nodeOffset: DpOffset,
    onNodeOffsetChanged: (DpOffset) -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        border = NodeBodyBorderStroke,
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .padding(NodeBodyPadding)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                    onNodeOffsetChanged(nodeOffset + DpOffset(dragAmount.x.toDp(), dragAmount.y.toDp()))
                }
            }
    ) {
        Box(Modifier.padding(NodeBodyPadding)) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

What I find, however, is that inside `detectDragGestures`, the `nodeOffset` value never changes. I have debugged, and `onNodeOffsetChanged` is definitely called with the new value. That is received from the next function out, which correctly replaces the graph with a whole new graph, where the node now has the new offset. But then, when the next call to `detectDragGestures` occurs, it is like this has never happened. The `nodeOffset` value is the same as the previous time, and the end result is the node "bouncing" in-place while I try to drag it away.

I don't know what the proper way to fix this is.

What I have observed, though, is that by having the method take `MutableState<DpOffset>` instead, it works as expected.

But I'm trying to use an immutable graph object as my state at the caller, and I can't see a straightforward way to get the offset of one node as a `MutableState`. If I change the offset to just *be* mutable, yeah, that will work, but then the graph will no longer be immutable.

Is there a good way to deal with this - i.e. a way to get a `MutableState` which is somehow backed by my immutable object? At the moment, my `Graph` class is *very* immutable:

```kotlin
data class Graph(
    val nodes: List<Node> = emptyList(),
    val links: List<Link> = emptyList(),
) {
    // ...
}
data class Node(
    val id: String,
    val offset: DpOffset,
    val userData: Any
)

// ...
val (graph, setGraph) = remember { mutableStateOf(Graph()) }
```

But I'm wondering whether I should be cutting my losses and introducing mutability into the model. There are various levels at which I could be doing it. For instance, the actual `offset` inside `Node` could just be `MutableState<DpOffset>`. And yeah, given that while you're dragging things around, the offset changes very frequently, that might be the right choice for efficiency? Although it completely removes the warm and fuzzy feeling one gets by making models completely immutable. :(